# How do I use ReadFile with getContents in do?

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to take a user input string and read a dictionary into my main loop but whenever I try to check if my string is in the dictionary, I get a false return.

```
 main = do
    charStream <- getContents
    contents   <- readFile "/usr/share/dict/words"
    let word = charStream
    let listDict = lines contents
    putStr (show (elem charStream listDict))
```

I would appreciate it if I could be pointed in the right direction. How do I take user input and read a file at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess: your input stream has a newline in it. Use `lines` or `words` or similar on `charStream`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getLine](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:getLine) if you only need to read a single word. E.g. `word <- getLine` and modify the binding used with `elem` (currently `charStream`). If you want to keep using `getContents`: press *Ctrl+d* (EOF) after typing the word instead of *Enter* to end the stream.